# How to create many blocks of memory with one reference in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I am trying to allocate blocks of memory for my program. I need to allocate 8 blocks of memory each having 62500bytes ( sizeof Int * 32 ) . In a way I am allocating 2,000,000 bit for each block (total number of blocks are 8).

I tried using `int *a= (int*) calloc(62500 * 8, sizeof(int))` and I use

```
int i=0;
for (i = 0; i < 62500 * 8; i++) {

            blk[i] = i;
        }
```

I use the above to allocate a value to each address so that it is easy to keep track of which index I need to fetch, since unlike array which are consecutive blocks of memory , if I use calloc I do not get consecutive memory addresses. But my problem here is I want each of 8 blocks allocated with a start index as 0 and end as 62500.Like `block1(0...62500) , block2(0...62500),block3(0...62500) ... block8(0...62500)`. I am not sure how to get this kind of structure.

I started with something like:

```
typedef struct block { 

int b;      

} blk;
```

How do I make a `struct *blk = {block1,block2,block3...block8}`, So that I can reach to each block from pointer *blk.

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, if you need to allocate large blocks that are persistent, you are usually better off using a system call to allocate the memory rather than a library function.

Answer (score 2):

Get a pointer to an array of arrays.

```
#define BLK_SZ 62500
#define BLK_NMEMB 8
```

The parentheses here denote that blk is a pointer to an array, rather than an array of pointers.

```
int (*block)[BLK_SZ][BLK_NMEMB] = calloc(62500 * 8, sizeof(int));
```

Note that the cast is unnecessary because void * is guaranteed to convert to any other pointer type. Now you can address it like:

```
(*block)[0][9001] = 14;
```

You can also create a typedef:

```
typedef int blk[BLK_SZ][BLK_NMEMB];
```

Which can then be used as:

```
blk *block = calloc(BLK_SZ * BLK_NMEMB, sizeof(int));
```

and addressed in the same manner as above.

If you really must, you can do:

```
typedef struct {
    int block0[BLK_SZ];
    int block1[BLK_SZ];
    int block2[BLK_SZ];
    int block3[BLK_SZ];
    int block4[BLK_SZ];
    int block5[BLK_SZ];
    int block6[BLK_SZ];
    int block7[BLK_SZ];
} blk;
```

and:

```
blk *block = calloc(BLK_SZ * BLK_NMEMB, sizeof(int));
```

accesed by

```
(*block).block0[9001] = 14;
```

Comment: shouldn't you replace 62500\*8 with BLK_SZ*BLK_NMEMB?

Comment: Also, you can spell out BLOCK_SIZE and BLOCK_NUM_MEMBERS (or NUM_BLOCKS), it's not 1980 any more.

Comment: First two comments: Yes; corrected.
@immibis If in 2015 typing more is somehow more pleasant than it was in 1980, sure.